# java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.icesoft.faces.webapp.CompatResourceServlet

Tags: jsf, jboss, integration, icefaces

I am having issues trying to deploy icefaces application on jboss v6, from error it appears that `com.icesoft.faces.webapp.CompatResourceServlet` but i have that class present in `icefaces-compat.jar` and it is properly deployed in application but still am having this issue, any thoughts or suggestions?

```
ERROR [AbstractKernelController] Error installing to PreReal: name=vfs://jboss-server/server/all/deploy/rwt.ear state=PostClassLoader mode=Manual requiredSta
te=PreReal: org.jboss.deployers.spi.DeploymentException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.icesoft.faces.webapp.CompatResourceServlet from BaseClassLoader@13d8fb0{vfs://jboss-server/server/all/deploy/krw.ear/rwt.war/}
        at org.jboss.resteasy.integration.deployers.ResteasyScannerDeployer.checkDeclaredApplicationClassAsServlet(ResteasyScannerDeployer.java:257) [:6.0.0.Final]
        at org.jboss.resteasy.integration.deployers.ResteasyScannerDeployer.scan(ResteasyScannerDeployer.java:108) [:6.0.0.Final]
        at org.jboss.resteasy.integration.deployers.ResteasyScannerDeployer.internalDeploy(ResteasyScannerDeployer.java:64) [:6.0.0.Final]
        at org.jboss.deployers.spi.deployer.helpers.AbstractRealDeployer.deploy(AbstractRealDeployer.java:55) [:2.2.0.GA]
        at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployerWrapper.deploy(DeployerWrapper.java:179) [:2.2.0.GA]
        at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployersImpl.doDeploy(DeployersImpl.java:1832) [:2.2.0.GA]
        at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployersImpl.doInstallParentFirst(DeployersImpl.java:1550) [:2.2.0.GA]
        at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployersImpl.doInstallParentFirst(DeployersImpl.java:1603) [:2.2.0.GA]
        at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployersImpl.install(DeployersImpl.java:1491) [:2.2.0.GA]
        at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractControllerContext.install(AbstractControllerContext.java:379) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.GA]
        at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.install(AbstractController.java:2044) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.GA]
        at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.incrementState(AbstractController.java:1083) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.GA]
        at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.executeOrIncrementStateDirectly(AbstractController.java:1322) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.GA]
        at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.resolveContexts(AbstractController.java:1246) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.GA]
        at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.resolveContexts(AbstractController.java:1139) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.GA]
        at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.change(AbstractController.java:939) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.GA]
        at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.change(AbstractController.java:654) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.GA]
        at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployersImpl.change(DeployersImpl.java:1983) [:2.2.0.GA]
        at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployersImpl.process(DeployersImpl.java:1076) [:2.2.0.GA]
        at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.main.MainDeployerImpl.process(MainDeployerImpl.java:679) [:2.2.0.GA]
        at org.jboss.system.server.profileservice.deployers.MainDeployerPlugin.process(MainDeployerPlugin.java:106) [:6.0.0.Final]
        at org.jboss.profileservice.dependency.ProfileControllerContext$DelegateDeployer.process(ProfileControllerContext.java:143) [:0.2.2]
        at org.jboss.profileservice.dependency.ProfileDeployAction.deploy(ProfileDeployAction.java:151) [:0.2.2]
        at org.jboss.profileservice.dependency.ProfileDeployAction.installActionInternal(ProfileDeployAction.java:94) [:0.2.2]
        at org.jboss.kernel.plugins.dependency.InstallsAwareAction.installAction(InstallsAwareAction.java:54) [jboss-kernel.jar:2.2.0.GA]
        at org.jboss.kernel.plugins.dependency.InstallsAwareAction.installAction(InstallsAwareAction.java:42) [jboss-kernel.jar:2.2.0.GA]
        at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.action.SimpleControllerContextAction.simpleInstallAction(SimpleControllerContextAction.java:62) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.GA]
        at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.action.AccessControllerContextAction.install(AccessControllerContextAction.java:71) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.GA]
        at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractControllerContextActions.install(AbstractControllerContextActions.java:51) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.GA]
        at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractControllerContext.install(AbstractControllerContext.java:379) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.GA]
        at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.install(AbstractController.java:2044) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.GA]
        at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.incrementState(AbstractController.java:1083) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.GA]
        at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.executeOrIncrementStateDirectly(AbstractController.java:1322) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.GA]
        at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.resolveContexts(AbstractController.java:1246) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.GA]
        at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.resolveContexts(AbstractController.java:1139) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.GA]
        at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.change(AbstractController.java:939) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.GA]
        at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.change(AbstractController.java:654) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.GA]
        at org.jboss.profileservice.dependency.ProfileActivationWrapper$BasicProfileActivation.start(ProfileActivationWrapper.java:190) [:0.2.2]
        at org.jboss.profileservice.dependency.ProfileActivationWrapper.start(ProfileActivationWrapper.java:87) [:0.2.2]
        at org.jboss.profileservice.dependency.ProfileActivationService.activateProfile(ProfileActivationService.java:215) [:0.2.2]
        at org.jboss.profileservice.dependency.ProfileActivationService.activate(ProfileActivationService.java:159) [:0.2.2]
        at org.jboss.profileservice.bootstrap.AbstractProfileServiceBootstrap.activate(AbstractProfileServiceBootstrap.java:112) [:0.2.2]
        at org.jboss.profileservice.resolver.BasicResolverFactory$ProfileResolverFacade.deploy(BasicResolverFactory.java:87) [:0.2.2]
        at org.jboss.profileservice.bootstrap.AbstractProfileServiceBootstrap.start(AbstractProfileServiceBootstrap.java:91) [:0.2.2]
        at org.jboss.system.server.profileservice.bootstrap.BasicProfileServiceBootstrap.start(BasicProfileServiceBootstrap.java:132) [:6.0.0.Final]
        at org.jboss.system.server.profileservice.bootstrap.BasicProfileServiceBootstrap.start(BasicProfileServiceBootstrap.java:56) [:6.0.0.Final]
        at org.jboss.bootstrap.impl.base.server.AbstractServer.startBootstraps(AbstractServer.java:827) [jboss-bootstrap-impl-base.jar:2.1.0-alpha-5]
        at org.jboss.bootstrap.impl.base.server.AbstractServer$StartServerTask.run(AbstractServer.java:417) [jboss-bootstrap-impl-base.jar:2.1.0-alpha-5]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619) [:1.6.0_18-ea]
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.icesoft.faces.webapp.CompatResourceServlet from BaseClassLoader@13d8fb0{vfs:///env/dev8/jboss-server/server/all/deploy/krw.ear/krw.
war/}
        at org.jboss.classloader.spi.base.BaseClassLoader.loadClass(BaseClassLoader.java:480) [jboss-classloader.jar:2.2.0.GA]
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:252) [:1.6.0_18-ea]
        at org.jboss.resteasy.integration.deployers.ResteasyScannerDeployer.checkDeclaredApplicationClassAsServlet(ResteasyScannerDeployer.java:253) [:6.0.0.Final]
        ... 48 more
```

**Update:**
Another important thing to note here is if I use eclipse plugin for IceFaces then application builds fine and deployments works great with JBoss 6 but if I remove those plugins and try to add jars in build path then nasty behavior as mentioned above begins, any suggestions or similar experience?

Looks like there is some issue with class loading mechanism that is causing some hickups here but somehow i am not able to figure it out.

Comment: I have tried multiple approaches but still am not able to resolve this issue, any thoughts?

Answer (score -1):

Make sure you have all the following jars in the Web-Inf/lib folder
**commons-logging-1.1.jar 
icefaces-3.3.0.jar 
 icefaces-ace-3.3.0.jar 
 icefaces-compat-3.3.0.jar 
 icepush-3.3.0.jar 
 javax.servlet-api-3.0.1.jar 
 jstl-1.2.jar**